# proper accordian menu not opening after form submit

Tags: jquery

I have   the  `$("#accordId").val()`  from servlet , which is the accordian Id before form submit, i want to open the same accordian.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        aId = $("#accordId").val();
        alert(aId);
        if(aId =="")
            aId = 0;
        $("#accordionCategory").accordion({
            collapsible  : true,
            active       : false,
            heightStyle  : "content",
            navigation   : true,
            active: aId
        });

});
```

The alert is giving proper result, but the proper accordin menu is not opening, please help

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        aId = $("#accordId").val();
        alert(aId);
        if(aId =="")
        { // here you foreget "{" 
  aId = 0;
        $("#accordionCategory").accordion({
            collapsible  : true,
            active       : false,
            heightStyle  : "content",
            navigation   : true,
            active: aId
        });
}

});
```

Comment: i think this will not help me, i want to set the accordian open pointed by aId --> coming from servlet

Comment: if(aId != 0) then set your accordian

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        aId = $("#accordId").val();
        alert(aId);
        if(aId =="")
            aId = 0;
        $("#accordionCategory").accordion({
            collapsible  : true,
            active       : false,
            heightStyle  : "content",
            navigation   : true,
            active: aId,
            form: "formname"
            change: function (form) {
            var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
            $(aId).val(index);
        }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        aId = parseInt($("#accordId").val());
        if(aId =="")
            aId = 0;
        $("#accordionCategory").accordion({
            collapsible  : true,
            active       : false,
            heightStyle  : "content",
            navigation   : true,
            active: aId,
            form: "formname"
            change: function (form) {
            var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
            $(aId).val(index);
        }
        });
});
```